# Accessing the IWebBrowser2 Document property returns empty

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, browser-automation

I am attempting to automate web data entry from a local access database using VBA.

After navigating to the website the login page will redirect to the main menu. However the IE object's document property returns nothing.

```
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "http://some.website.com.au/"
IE.Visible = True
With IE
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
    Loop
End with  
htmlDoc = IE.Document 
' At this point VBA fails as the IE.Document property is empty
....
```

I suspect that the issue is that after navigation to the website the landing page is a login page that checks a cookie and redirects. If i disable the cookie and use the code to login it works but past the login page the issue is the same.

The only credible information I found was that in the case of HTML Components a DHTML page will not have a document attached. This seems a little strange as the IE instance clearly has a document in it anyway.

Ive not been able to find anywhere else where this problem is documented so any help or direction would be appreciated, if you have encountered this situation or if you have a much better knowledge of the MSHTML classes to understand why this would be the case.

cheers,

Will

Comment: Hi OP, I would like to help, can you verify the code is complete? 
The `End With`,   `set htmlDoc = IE.Document` the `set` keyword. It would be best if you can provide any sample website with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Larry, The code is complete. Code after this point is irrelevant as it isnt run and wouldnt be unless the IE.document property returns a value.

Comment: The problem with the website im accessing is that it needs a login which i'm unwilling to publish. Its got a reasonable amount of java on it but nothing spectacular. Some AJAX as well but its all quite simple. @Larry

Comment: so, in your case, if you execute the code line by line, and before executing `**SET** htmlDoc = IE.Document`. If you add IE.Document to the watch windows in VBE, it's empty? Anyway, my approach to the problem would be using httpRequest http://tkang.blogspot.sg/2010/09/sending-http-post-request-with-vba.html to get the cookie, token you need

Comment: You should be able to get the HTML Document of the login page unless you are using http authentication?

Comment: I'm moving over to using XMLHTTP to directly communicate with the webserver which is a somewhat more fragile approach. At least slightly more fragile than browser automation as its totally sensitive to any change in the website but *seems* to be more productive so far.

Comment: Sadly it does mean that I need to replicate the functionality of all the javascript on the page that populates some of the hidden data which the browser automation would allow me to leverage but otherwise im happy with it as a solution. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: you worries are very solid, let's wait for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Larry try using [WinHttpRequest object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is a basic GET request adapted from Larry's [blog](http://tkang.blogspot.sg/2010/09/sending-http-post-request-with-vba.html) (just in case the link goes dead).

```
Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object
Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

myURL = "http://www.example.com/"

winHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
winHttpReq.Send

result = winHttpReq.responseText
```